# Jetty RESTful with multiple data formats

Tags: java, rest, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am a newbie in this area, I am using embedded jetty to create web services and I have few existing methods/pojos which I need to make as RESTful API's and I want support for multiple data formats like JSON/XML etc.. can anyone suggest a good tutorial or steps/suggestions.

I am using Java (Eclipse + Maven)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest method to build RESTful services on top of POJOs is to use JAX-RS (implemented via Jersey or Apache CXF, to give two examples). Those sorts of frameworks are then deployed (with your classes) inside a servlet container, such as Jetty.

I use CXF to serve up both XML and JSON off the same model classes (with the service interface described as an annotated interface, a nice approach). It works (provided you don't have abstract classes as arguments) and there are some [reasonable docs and tutorial examples](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/) online.

Comment: And yes, I was developing with Eclipse and Maven. And Jenkins for CI and lots of other goodies too…

Comment: will CXF works with jetty and maven? (I am a newbie in this field)